# how nest js handle db connection for read write queries?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, nestjs

in my project have one database, I am creating one read connection and one write connection.
But for the GET method, the select query is also excepting the write DB connection.

How to find, which DB connection is connecting for which request in nest js?

Comment: Can you show how you create and use these connections?

Comment: As far as I know nest does not handle it. It is handled by whatever library you want kysely/typeorm/sequelize/mikroorm etc

Comment: i am using sequelize